# Subdomain drupal sites cannot read domain cookies

Tags: 7, cookies, subsites

I have set a cookie from domain (.example.co) and its .NET platform & reading those cookie from drupal site(test.example.co).

While retrieving it shows empty, I have used [$_COOKIE](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php).

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919968/php-read-a-cookie-that-is-on-another-domain) suggests it is possible, also we are setting domain name while creating cookies? Is it possible to use while retrieving cookies?

Also i have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985593/unable-to-read-cookies-from-browser), is that interrelated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for you reply,

Finally reason has been found, since there is an DOT(.) in the cookie name set. It cannot be retrieved.

https://harrybailey.com/2009/04/dots-arent-allowed-in-php-cookie-names/

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide an appropriate value for [`$cookie_domain`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/cookie_domain/7.x) in settings.php.

e.g.

```
$cookie_domain = 'example.co';
```

That will allow you to set/retrieve cookies from example.co on foo.example.co, and vice versa.

Comment: i have updated my cookie domain to (.example.co) i can able to access my drupal session cookies  which are in (.example.co) but unlikely other cookie which am required :(

Comment: This isn't a Drupal thing, it's just how cookies work; whatever sets this other cookie just needs the same `domain=example.co` set on it

Comment: i have updated my query.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use other subdomains' cookies, you need to set both site's cookie domain to .example.com.

Comment: You need to remove the leading `.` to ensure greatest compatibility across older/modern browsers. If you're not concerned with supporting older browsers the leading `.` is ok, but will be ignored by the browser anyway. So might as well remove it altogether. See [RFC 2109](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2109) and [RFC 6265](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265) for the low-level explanations

Comment: Ah for me that's quite conflicting, my team and I tried to share cookies across subdomains but couldn't get it to work unless we had the leading period. We try not to support older browsers, so I guess for us at the mo, the leading period is ok. Would you suggest we give it another shot?

Comment: To be honest I’m just paraphrasing the RFCs and some related info (as I’ve understood them), I guess your mileage may well vary depending on circumstance